# Can't access API in react

Tags: reactjs

I am using react and nestjs,because my react project and the nest project are on the same server, I use 127.0.0.1 to access the API in react production mode, but I cannot access the service. Then I run the react project locally to access the API through the server ip and there is no problem. Where is the mistake?

#### web project in server

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/allposts net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the ip to your server ip. Sorry, I cannot access your image posted, so it is only my guess.

```
http://your-server-ip:8000/admin/allposts
```

Comment: 道理我都懂这样写服务器IP没问题，但是为啥localhost就不行呢，都在一台服务器上

Comment: localhost means your client pc, not your server